# VueRouter: Is it possible to have a smooth scroll down animation from one route to another?

Tags: vue.js, animation, css-animations, css-transitions, vue-router

I have a simple VueJS application where I have multiple routes. For a pair of routes, I want to have a scroll down and scroll up animation while routes change.

For example, I have a search/dropdown page, where after the search result from the dropdown is selected, I want to take him to the details page but with a scroll down animation. So that the user feels he is still on the same page.

I have tried using the VuePageTransition library. That is indeed a great library but does not have this specific animation that I need.

Update:
I tried the following code. It gives a scroll-like animation but the leaving page is shown going down but the coming page is not shown during the animation.

In the template in App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

In the style tag,

```
.slide-enter {
}

.slide-enter-active {
    animation: slide-in-coming 2s ease-out forwards;
}

.slide-leave {

}

.slide-leave-active {
    animation: slide-in 2s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(800px);
    }
}

@keyframes slide-in-coming {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-800px);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by scroll-down animation? Are your routes "sections" of the same page? Or do you want the new page to be appended to the current one, scroll down from first to second and then remove the initial page?

Comment: @tao I want to give the user experience such that the new page is appended after the current page.

Comment: You have to animate `-leave-to` from `magin-top: 0` to `magin-top: -100%`. Without animating the one entering at all, because it's already animated by the first one, which is moving up. If you can't make it work, create a codesandbox.io with what you have and i'll have a look. And mode should be `in-out`, of course (you want both displayed during the transition, right?)